# Differential of a two variable's inverse functoin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

Let the function $f: \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ be one-to-one and $C^1$, and g be its inverse ($f\circ g=id$). We know that the derivation of a linear map is itself. Namely, $D(f\circ g)(x,y)=D(id)(x,y)=id(x,y)$, which is a $2*1$ matrix. On the other hand, by chain rule: $D(f\circ g)(x,y)= Df(g(x,y))\cdot Dg(x,y)$, which will give us a $2*2$ matrix.
I am sure the second result (i.e. $2*2$ matrix) is right, but I cannot see where I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$D(\text{id})(x,y)=\text{id}(x,y)$ and the $\text{id}$ is interpreted as the matrix $(a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq 2}$, where $a_{1,1}=1$, $a_{1,2}=0$, $a_{2,1}=0$, and $a_{2,2}=1$.

Comment: To elaborate slightly, the identity is a linear map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, given by $\text{id}(x,y) = (x,y)$. This is given (in any basis) by the matrix just provided.

Comment: I know that id is the identity matrix, so when it acts on a point, it gives the point itself, namely, id(x,y)=(x,y) as @Ted Shifrin pointed out. While it seems that we should have id itself instead, not id(x,y).

Comment: Yes, that's right. The composition of the derivatives is the identity mapping, not its value at $(x,y)$.

Comment: Sorry for asking many q's, but what we had was $D(id)(x,y)=id(x,y)$. It's not equal to the matrix $id$ itself. It is rather the matrix acting on the point, which gives the point (not the id matrix). I know that it should be equal (to make sense for the composition of derivatives), but I don't see how to get the equality. In its one dimensional analog,x=g(y), taking the derivative would be one on the left side, which should be the identity matrix in several dim. However, it doesn't turn out to be so following my computations, which is exactly my question, that where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: If $T$ is a linear operator, then the value $T(x,y)$ is of the form $(u,v)$, and if we find the matrix representation $A$ of the linear operator $T$, then $[u ~v]^{T}=A[x ~y]^{T}$.